# How to change a Private Site logo with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am trying to change the logo of a private site through PowerShell, but whenever I try the system changes it back to a new logo.

I add the new logo to the 'Site Assets' library and then use the
Set-PnPWeb -SetSiteLogoUrl command.

What appears to happen is that the system creates a logo for the site when the site is first created, it then sets the logo to be the one that I have added to the site, then the system creates another new logo and assigns that logo to be the logo for the site. This second logo seems to be created and applied in response to the logo that I have uploaded.

I am unsure how to go about solving this issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

since you mentioned private site i assume this is Modern Team Site with Private Group. To set logo for modern team site you need to use `Set-PnPSite` command and use `-LogoFilePath`
 parameter to set the logo `Set-PnPWeb` is used in case of Classic team site.

Comment: Hi Akshay, thank you for replying and for your help :) I seem to still be receiving the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the below PowerShell coding :

```
#Add PowerShell Module for SharePoint Online

Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking

 

##Configuration variables

$SiteUrl = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/"

$LogoURL="/SiteAssets/Logo.png" #Existing file

 

Try {

    #Get Credentials to connect

    $Cred = Get-Credential

    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

 

    #Setup the context

    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)

    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

    $Web = $Ctx.Web

 

    #Change Logo

    $Web.SiteLogoUrl = $LogoURL

    $Web.Update()

    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

 

    Write-host "Logo Updated Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green

}

Catch {

    write-host -f Red "Error updating Logo!" $_.Exception.Message

}
```

Reference URL :

[SharePoint Online: How to Change Site Logo using PowerShell?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/sharepoint-online-how-to-change-logo-using-powershell.html?m=1)